# What is the opposite expression of "She is my boss" or what is the general term for someone who is a subordinate?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

"**My boss**" is a general term for the person who is in charge of me.

I am looking for a general term for the person who I am in charge of.

For example, "**he is my subordinate/employee**" but "**subordinate/employee**" is too formal.

In Vietnamese, we say "**he is my soldier**" (literally translated from Vietnamese). This means he works under me or I am in charge of him, not actually talking about a soldier in the army.

**Do we have such a word like that in English?**

Answer (score 2):

A common term in the commercial business world (not usually on a farm, for example) is “[direct report](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/direct-report)”. Of course, this implies that the subordinate reports directly to the superior.

> I am his boss, and he is my direct report.

Comment: "direct report" sounds like a British term. Do American people say it?

Comment: Yes, it is frequently used here in New York. In fact, I was worried that it might not be used in Britain, but the linked definition says both US and UK.

Comment: But, "my boss" can be used in non-business setup. For example, my friend and I are  investigating a case and he plans everything and I just do as he says. Can I say "**I am his direct report**"?

Comment: No, you are not the direct report of your friend except perhaps in a figurative sense. That term is usually used only in a work environment.

Answer (score 1):

These are many alternatives for "subordinates" and "people under me": staff, team, team members, teammates, workers, assistants, associates, individual contributors. Another excellent option is to use people's job titles!

Source: [Business Writing](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2009/04/subordinatesa-word-to-avoid.html)